# Non duplicate return PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code here:

```
$users_in_pot = "SELECT count(*) FROM `pot$ID`";
$result = $db->prepare($users_in_pot); 
$result->execute(); 
$number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
```

I want to check only for non duplicate entries in the pot.

For example:
User A: Bets 1
User A: Bets 1

It will return 2.
 My idea is to return 1 as it is the same user.

I am sorry for my english!

Thanks!

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` on the column which contains the user identifier http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html

Comment: Could you provide a snippet ?

Comment: Click on the link, there are enough examples.

Comment: DISTINCT and/or GROUP BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As above suggested `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` both can be used like below:-

```
$users_in_pot = "SELECT DISTINCT(user_name) FROM `pot$ID`"; // if column nae is user_name

Or 

$users_in_pot = "SELECT count(*) FROM `pot$ID` GROUP BY user_name";

$result = $db->prepare($users_in_pot); 
$result->execute(); 
$number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked :)